# Connecting Android App to RESTful Web Service

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, androidhttpclient

The user will have to input both title and number into two EditText. once he click submit, what he wrote in the EditText will be converted to String.
Now the problem am facing is, how can i POST these Strings to the RESTful Web Service

Here is my code

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String tit = null;
            String number = null;

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:3000/api");

            if(title.getText()!=null){
                tit = title.getText().toString();
            }
            if(num.getText()!=null){
                number = num.getText().toString();
            }
        }
    });
```

please anyone can guide me or direct me on how to do it.

Comment: have you tried to google?

Comment: yup, I tried many examples, non could solve my problem XD

Comment: so did you get any errors? what is expected result? what is actual result? show what have you tried. you should improve your question, it is too broad

Answer (score 0):

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       String tit = null;
       String number = null;

       HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:3000/api");

       if(title.getText()!=null){
          tit = title.getText().toString();
       }
       if(num.getText()!=null){
          number = num.getText().toString();
       }

       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", tit));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number", number));
       httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

    }
});
```

Comment: And also you have to do some changes in your server code which receive these parameters

Answer (score 0):

@Assad never make Network stuff on UI thread.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tit = title.getText().toString();
                String number = num.getText().toString();

                new PostDataTask().execute(new String[] { tit, number });

            }
        });
```

Make Http request in [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or under other worker thread

```
class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:3000/api");

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", params[0]));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number", params[1]));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                // HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

                String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
                return true;
            } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result) {
                // success
            } else {
                // failure
            }

        }

    }
```